# Filtering a Scala List

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I need to create function that takes double and returns new list, based on the first one, that includes absolute values of elements grom the first list that belongs to the range of <-5,12>. I need to use filtering. I have an idea, but it's not working. I'm sorry, maybe my question is easy, but I'm a begginer :)

```
var numbersReal = List(2.25, -1, -3, 7.32, 0.25, -6, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2.99, 3.02, 0)
 
 def magicFilter(list: List[Double]): List[Double] = {
    var newList = List[Double]()
    list.foreach {element => if (-5 <= element && element <= 12) newList += scala.math.abs(element) }
    newList.toList
 }
println(magicFilter(numbersReal))
```

Comment: Stay away from `foreach()`. It doesn't do what you think. Use `filter()` to get the desired elements and `map()` to modify them.

Comment: Your example doesn't work because of `List` append operator is not `+` but `:+`. By the way, in scala is better not to use `var`s. So it will work: `newList = newList :+ scala.math.abs(element)` but look at answers, there are better solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Best Practice Solution

You can do this easily with a combination of

- `filter`: keep only elements that satisfy a given predicate / condition. For us, it will be keeping only elements in [-5,12]
- `map`: apply a function to every element. For us, it will be taking the absolute value.

```scala
numbersReal.filter(e => e >= -5 && e <= 12).map(math.abs)
```

Another way to achieve this in "one-shot" is to use `collect` which combines both `filter` and `map`:

```
numbersReal.collect { case e if e >= 5 && e <= 12 => math.abs(e) }
```

I personally find the first solution to be more readable in this particular case, but that's a matter of opinion.

Usually, these problems can be solved without resorting to a `var` or any mutable collection. Scala's collections are one of its greatest assets because they include a lot of these primitive operations, and most problems can be solved by combining them.

---

### Note regarding your proposed solution

Your solution is not wrong per-se, but it is very error-prone to implement logic that is already part of collection methods like `filter`, `map` and `collect`. If you wanted to fix your approach, you just have to replace `newList += ...` with `newList :+= ...`. This is because adding an element to an immutable `List` is done with `list :+ element` (or `element +: list` if you want to prepend). The `list :+= element` is syntactic sugar for `list = list :+ element`. Again, these are not constructs you should encounter very often, because this style is generally frowned-upon except if you know you have a very good reason to use mutability.